# Training a ranker with train.py script

Tags: python, python-2.7, solr, ibm-cloud, retrieve-and-rank

I'm currently trying to create a ranker by running the `train.py` script provided by the Retrieve & Rank Documentation.

I issue the following command when trying to create the ranker:

```
train.py -u usernameHere:PasswordHere -i  Mainframe_Batch_Automation_CA7.csv -c clusterIdHere -x Mainframe_Batch_Automation_CA7 -n Mainframe_Batch_Automation_CA7
```

And I receive the following error:

```
Input file is Mainframe_Batch_Automation_CA7.csv
Solr cluster is sc0c2398d4_d087_4516_99dd_10c25cc06b0a
Solr collection is Mainframe_Batch_Automation_CA7
Ranker name is Mainframe_Batch_Automation_CA7
Rows per query 10
Generating training data...

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\Documents\Retrieve & Rank\train.py", line 83, in <module>
    process = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(curl_cmd), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 390, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 640, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the specified file
```

At first I thought it was because Python wasn't in my PATH environment variable but after adding it to the PATH variable it still gives me the same error ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Script runs curl command which connects to solr and ranker urls. This error is due to firewall issues. Try to execute the script outside firewall.

Comment: That's why it was not working ... my curl wasn't working, I just added curl to the windows PATH and now it's working! Thank you.